# Free media player with jump-to-specific-time option for big mp3 files

Tags: mediaplayer

I'm listening to some mp3 files, some of them lasting 5 hours or more, and I'm looking for a player which allows to jump directly to a specific point in time in the mp3 file.

VLC has an option "jump to time" but it's buggy, it doesn't do anything or just hangs the app. Each time I reopen any player I've tried so far, I have to guess and click the time progress bar trying to find where I left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you aware of iTunes' option to remember the play position in a file? Right-click on any track (or select it and press <kbd>Cmd-I</kbd>) to open it.

[image: Get Info]

Comment: I can't find that option in iTunes>Preferences>playback or any other tab in iTunes 11.1.3

Comment: @rraallvv It's available by right-clicking an item in iTunes and selecting Get Info (or by selecting an item and pressing ⌘I) and going to the Options tab.

Answer (score 1):

You could [assign a shortcut to a script](https://superuser.com/questions/153890/assign-a-shortcut-to-running-a-script-in-os-x/264943#264943) like this:

```
set text item delimiters to ":"
display dialog "" default answer ""
set ti to text items of text returned of result
if number of ti is 1 then
    item 1 of ti
else if number of ti is 2 then
    60 * (item 1 of ti) + (item 2 of ti)
else if number of ti is 3 then
    3600 * (item 1 of ti) + 60 * (item 2 of ti) + (item 3 of ti)
end if
tell application "iTunes" to set player position to result
```

Or install ffmpeg with `brew install ffmpeg --with-afplay` and use a command like `ffplay -ss 1:23:45 file.mp3`.

I also use scripts like this to change the playback position with the keyboard:

```
try
    tell application "iTunes"
        if player position < 15 then
            previous track
        else
            set player position to player position - 15
        end if
    end tell
end try
```

```
try
    tell application "iTunes"
        set player position to player position + 15
    end tell
end try
```